# Welcome Email not getting sent to community users on register

Tags: community, email, email-template, security, customer-community

I have run into an issue where if I am unchecking a checkbox: 'Let guest users see other members of this community' under general setting in Preferences.
If the check box is checked, welcome emails are getting triggered.
We unchecked it due to some security issues. But I am not sure what is the relation between this and sending email.

We send the welcome emails using standard "Welcome New Member" functionality of communities.

Do Anyone know whats wrong here.

[image]

Comment: we are having a similar issue. Did you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to select "Send Welcome Email" on **Emails** Menu

[image]

Please, take into account the following:

Salesforce sends welcome emails when:

- A community changes from Preview status to Active status. An inactive community doesn’t receive emails unless the associated org has a default portal or if the user’s profile is part of an active portal.
- An admin adds a profile or permission set to an active community.
- A user of an active community is assigned a profile or permission set.

read more about it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_email.htm&type=5)

Comment: I had checked this checkbox. But still issue was there. We have raised this with salesforce. Will post If we get some answer.  The issue reproduces on sandboxes only and not  on production.  Also only if,  if I am unchecking a checkbox: 'Let guest users see other members of this community' under general setting in Preferences the issue occurs else it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you activate the community.

Administration > Settings > Activate

Comment: Hi Sébastien, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask] and [answer] if you haven't already. Just a heads up, if you put questions in your `Answer` posts, they will often get flagged as low quality, even if your answer in and of itself is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late to this Question but people might find it helpful.

We have done all the above answers but still we did not receive the welcome email for new user. Then I have activated this 'Let guest users see other members of this site' permission under Administration -> Preferences and then the users started receiving welcome email
[image]