# Community : Welcome email (Visualforce) is not sent

Tags: community, email-template, self-registration

Please note the following

1. Community is active
2. `Send welcome email` is checked
3. User profile is added as members of the community
4. Issue is happening in sandbox and production
5. An apex class handles user creation for self registered users
6. Welcome email template is of type visualforce to handle email content based on user language

But the welcome email is not sent unless `Let guest users see other members of this community` is enabled under community settings.

We don't want to enable this option and don't really see the correlation between this setting and welcome email.

To be noted that as per this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_GUV_disabled.htm&type=5&release=228), `Let guest users see other members of this community` **impacts data privacy** and is turned off by default since Winter '21 release .

Here is the visualforce template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_Subject} {!$Network.Name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Network"
language="{!Recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
<body>
    {!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_Greetings}
    {!IF($Network.Name != 'Company Name', Recipient.FirstName , '')}
    <p>{!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_BodyLine1}</p>
    <p>{!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_BodyLine2} {!Recipient.Email} {!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_BodyLine3} </p>
    <p> {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails} </p>
    <p> {!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_BodyLine4} </p>

<p>{!$Label.Regards} </p>
<p>{!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_FinalGreetings}</p>
</body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

We are aware of similar questions on this topic but there is no clear answer on the root cause and possible solution : 
[Welcome Email not getting sent to community users on register](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316786/welcome-email-not-getting-sent-to-community-users-on-register) 
[Site.createExternalUser not sending out welcome email to user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294354/site-createexternaluser-not-sending-out-welcome-email-to-user/317534?noredirect=1#comment533091_317534)

Case raised with support has not provided useful info.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This may be late to this Question but people might find it helpful.

We have done all the above answers but still we did not receive the welcome email for new user. Then I have activated this 'Let guest users see other members of this site' permission under Administration -> Preferences and then the users started receiving welcome email
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your emailTemplate header as follows:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!$Label.Community_Welcome_Note_Subject} {!$Network.Name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Community" renderUsingSystemContextWithoutSharing="true" 
language="{!Recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}">
```

renderUsingSystemContextWithoutSharing="true" was the fix allow access to the user record.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_templates_vf_modify_for_guest.htm&type=5